# Missing libSM.so.6 library - QT creator installation error

Tags: 14.04, libraries

when i trying to ran qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86-offline.run I gets below error.

**./qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86-offline.run: error while loading shared libraries: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

I have installed Qt before but I didn't get any error.
I think the cause should below command

**sudo apt-get autoremove**

I ran this command to my newly installed ubuntu.
I found this article online

**http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/install-lolibfiles.html**

so I ran below command

**sudo apt-get install libice6 libsm6 libxt6 libxrender1 libfontconfig1 libcups2**

but terminal says its already installed

**libsm6 is already the newest version**

can anyone tell me a way to install qt creater

Comment: post the output of `apt-cache policy libsm6`

Comment: libsm6:
  Installed: 2:1.2.1-2
  Candidate: 2:1.2.1-2
  Version table:
 *** 2:1.2.1-2 0
        500 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: and `ldconfig -p | grep libSM.so.6`?

Comment: libSM.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> libSM.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6

The program requires 32-bit libraries. You need `libsm6:i386`

```
sudo apt-get install libsm6:i386
```

And now, `ldconfig -p | grep libSM.so.6` should look like this:

```
libSM.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6
libSM.so.6 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6
```

And for all other missing libraries use the same strategy:

e.g. `libXrender.so.1`

```
$ apt-file search libXrender.so.1
libxrender1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1
libxrender1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
libxrender1-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0

$ sudo apt-get install libxrender1:i386
```

Comment: Now I'm getting new error 

./qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86-offline.run: error while loading shared libraries: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: I have improved my answer. :)

Comment: I saw it later :) 

I found about this command 

**sudo apt-get install qtcreator**  

It installed the qtcreator but I'm worried because terminal said size is 100 MB or something but offline installer 465 MB. 
What is different between them?

Comment: @MenukaIshan I can not answer satisfactorily you. Without the right to look at, I can only guess.

Comment: @MenukaIshan Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)

Comment: I would love to but it require 15 reputations :/  I'm sorry I tried it

Comment: @MenukaIshan But  you can click the ✓ :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23054/discussion-between-menuka-ishan-and-a-b).